# Find a function $g : [−1, 1] \to \mathbb R$ with $|g(x)| < |x|^4$ for which $g ′′(0)$ does not exist.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, inequality

For this question, I couldn't think of one function for g, based on what I know, $g'(c)= \frac{g(a)-g(b)}{a-b}$. and $g''(c)= \frac{(g'(a)-g'(b))}{(a-b)}$, but how do we exactly show $g''(0)$ doesn't exist?

Comment: Try $g(x) = x^{\alpha} \sin(x^{-\beta})$ for some well-chosen $\alpha, \beta > 0$.

Comment: (The above, but it won't work at $x=0$ for the question as stated because you cannot have the strict inequality $|f(0)|<0$ for any value of $f(0)$)

Comment: I assume the strict inequality is just a typo.

Comment: @Raoul or the inequality was meant to hold everywhere except 0. Regardless the main point of the exercise is contained in your comment

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f:[-1,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by :

$$f(x)=x^4\sin\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)\text{ if }x\neq0\text{ and }0\text{ otherwise}$$

It is clear that $f$ is $C^\infty$ on $[-1,0)\cup (0,1]$.

Since $\vert f(x)\vert\leqslant x^4$ for all $x\in [-1,1]$, we see that $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=0=f(0)}$. This proves that $f$ is continuous at $0$.

Moreover, for all $x\neq0$ :

$$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}=x^3\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\underset{x\to 0}{\rightarrow}0$$which proves that $f$ is differentiable at $0$ and $f'(0)=0$.

For all $x\neq0$ :
$$f'(x)=4x^3\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)-2x\cos\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\underset{x\to 0}{\rightarrow}0=f'(0)$$which proves that $f'$ is continuous at $0$.

Now, for all $x\neq0$ :
$$\frac{f'(x)-f'(0)}{x}=4x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)-2\cos\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$doesn't have any limit at $0$.
This proves that $f$ is **not** twice differentiable.

**EDIT**

Finally, if we multiply $f$ by some $A\in(0,1)$ (say $A=0.9$ for example), we get a function with the desired properties (strict inequality for any $x\in[-1,0)\cup (0,1]$).

Comment: one can multiply by a small constant to achieve $<|x|^4$ except at 0

Comment: @CalvinKhor That's true ... Let me edit my answer.